# How to implement a ssh tunnel base vpn in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel, socks5

this is my first question at this comunity, so please forgive me if I made a mistake in asking the question

I want to connect to my server through Flutter and the ssh command and pass all the traffic of my application through the tunnel like a VPN through port forwarding and a socks5 proxy.

Currently, there are some Github projects that do this for android and for now android is enough for me.
One example I found is [ConnectBot](https://github.com/connectbot/connectbot), and it first connects to the server with the ssh command, then executes a portForwarding command on the server.
Then we can use a socks5 proxy and port in our apps by starting the service.
But I need a tunnel, not just a proxy

There are several Android applications in the Play Store, such as [netmod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netmod.syna&hl=en&gl=US), that do this
that's mean
1- Connecting to the server through ssh
2- Port forwarding
3- Running socks proxy
4- Tunneling the traffic of the entire device

Please help if you have any information about this
thank you